# Website does not run properly through index.html

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

I have created a website with HTML, CSS and java script via Visual Studio code and as usual I have seen all changes via live server.
Through live server you can see everything properly and run everything well but if you click directly in folder on index.html then you get almost nothing. pics links and etc, not will run.
does anyone know why it is like this?
(I would like the site to be fully executable offline).

### **Run via VS Code Live Server**

[image: Run via VS Code Live Server]

### **Run direct via index.html**

[image: Run direct via index.html]

Comment: This implies that something gets executed on the server before it is sent to the browser. Check your console to see what's going on.

Comment: okay and what could be ?

Comment: Without looking at your code it is impossible to tell.

Comment: is that enough?

https://codepen.io/namisrn/pen/KKNgGdZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that you are linking them wrong. `../Img/Logo.png` could be a wrong directory, although it is impossible to tell without showing your directory structure